# What kind of parameter that can pass variables inside a Unit in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, parameters, android-adapter

I am confuse about what kind of parameter should I pass from the main class to the recycler adapter class that have parameter type like this

```
class RecyclerAdapter(private val clickListener:(view: View, movieName: String)
    ->Unit):ListAdapter<MovieInfo,RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>(Diff())
```

In the main class, my plan is to declare the adapter like below

```
val adapter = RecyclerAdapter() //missing parameter inside the ()
```

I have never seen a class parameter like that before. Usually, it is a starightforward list data type such as `RecyclerAdapter(private val dressList: List<DressList.DressName>)`. Maybe if I know some examples about that kind of parameter, it can give me some enlightenment about what parameter should I pass. Thanks.

Comment: That is a callback function parameter. You can pass a lambda function or a reference to any function that fits the signature. Read here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html

Answer (score 1):

Just to break this down

```
val name: String
```

That's simple enough - the variable is called *name*, and its *type* is `String`. If that's a parameter, you need to pass a `String` there.

```
val clickListener: () -> Unit
```

The type here is `() -> Unit`, which is a *function*. You know how you call a function by putting `()` after the name, like `toString()`? That's what that represents in the type, a function that takes no parameters. The `->` is showing the type it *produces* (or *returns* if you like). This is a function that takes no parameters, and produces no value (aka `Unit`).

```
val clickListener: (view: View, movieName: String) -> Unit
// or more typically with just the types
val clickListener: (View, String) -> Unit
```

This is similar, except this type is a function that *does* take parameters - a `View` and a `String`, and returns nothing. When you call this function, you're expected to pass those values into it, and the function does something with them.

---

The setup you have here is basically an Adapter that's displaying `MovieInfo` objects, and in the constructor you pass in a listener function. So when the user clicks an item, that function gets called with the relevant values. It means a component *outside* of the adapter can decide what actually happens when something gets clicked, by providing a function that does the necessary stuff. The adapter doesn't need to know any of those details - it just needs to pass the listener function the data it requires.

---

I don't know what you're doing with this:

```
val clickListener = movieList.fold(Unit, { view, movieName -> Unit })
```

but if you hover over `clickListener` you'll see its inferred type is `Unit`. This isn't *a function object*, this is *the result of **calling** the `fold` function*. You've run `fold` over your `movieList`, basically returning `Unit` at each step, and the result is `Unit`. That's what you're trying to pass as your `clickListener` parameter.

A function would be in `{ }` braces (or a function reference like `::handleClick`), like this:

```
val clickListener = { view, movieName -> // do stuff that returns unit }
```

and if you really wanted to do a *fold* for some reason, you can do it in there! But it's usually a function that does something like display a movie, add it to some list or a database, that kind of thing. An action in response to a click

Answer (score 0):

private val clickListener:(view: View, movieName: String) this is basically call back function and ->Unit is lambda function where Unit represent return type of function

Unit in kotlin same working as in java a void type

Answer (score 0):

You should [read the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html) on functional type syntax and lambda syntax to understand how to interpret this. You don't need to be doing anything with Unit. Unit is the type your lambda should be returning.

The functional type in this case has a return type of Unit. That just means it doesn't return anything useful. Unit is the default return type of any function that doesn't really return anything, so when you see `->Unit` as part of the function type, it means your lambda doesn't need to return anything.

In this case, you can use Trailing Lambda Syntax (which is also explained in the above link), which means you can omit the parentheses. Something like this:

```
val adapter = RecyclerAdapter { view, movieName -> 
     // your code for what to do whenever an item in this adapter is clicked
}
```

I don't know what you were trying to do with `fold` in your comment. The documentation uses `fold` as an example of a higher order function, so it is showing you how to call a higher order function. It is not telling you that you should use `fold` to create a functional type! `fold` is just an example of a higher order function. Your RecyclerAdapter constructor is also a higher order function.

Comment: I am confused. I have a fetchLocationUpdate function which returns a unit like `fetchLocationUpdates: ()->Unit`, but when I use it it throws "No value passed for parameter fetchLocationUpdates".

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam I would have to see the code of the function declaration and where you're calling it to be able to tell what's wrong.

Comment: It took me hours to understand this, can you explain the logic too? link to code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76822776/no-value-passed-for-parameter-fetchlocationupdates