# No value passed for parameter fetchLocationUpdates

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I have a simple problem understanding a basic issue of "No value passed for parameter fetchLocationUpdates" in my google maps app. I am not sure what to provide for the function rememberAppState() to resolve this issue. fetchLocationsUpdate is a function in my MainActivity.kt.

My BetteHomesApp.kt:

```
package com.example.bettehomes
import android.Manifest
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.ReadOnlyComposable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.example.bettehomes.common.composable.PermissionDialog
import com.example.bettehomes.common.composable.RationaleDialog
import com.example.bettehomes.common.snackbar.SnackbarManager
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.login.LoginScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.settings.SettingsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.sign_up.SignUpScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.splash.SplashScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.example.bettehomes.screens.map.MapsScreen
import com.example.bettehomes.theme.BetteHomesTheme
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.isGranted
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.rememberPermissionState
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.shouldShowRationale
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope


@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun BetteHomesApp() {
  BetteHomesTheme {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      RequestNotificationPermissionDialog()
    }

    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
        val appState = rememberAppState()

      Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
          SnackbarHost(
            hostState = it,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            snackbar = { snackbarData ->
              Snackbar(snackbarData, contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
            }
          )
        },
        //scaffoldState = appState.scaffoldState
      ) { innerPaddingModifier ->
        NavHost(
          navController = appState.navController,
          startDestination = MAP_SCREEN,
          modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier)
        ) {
          betteHomesGraph(appState)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun RequestNotificationPermissionDialog() {
  val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)

  if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
    if (permissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) RationaleDialog()
    else PermissionDialog { permissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }
  }
}

@Composable
fun rememberAppState(
  //scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(), this is replaced by snackbarHostState in material 3
  navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
  snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() },
  snackbarManager: SnackbarManager = SnackbarManager,
  resources: Resources = resources(),
  coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope(),
  fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit

  ) =
  remember(snackbarHostState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope, fetchLocationUpdates) {
    BetteHomesAppState(navController, snackbarHostState, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope, fetchLocationUpdates)
  }

@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun resources(): Resources {
  LocalConfiguration.current
  return LocalContext.current.resources
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.betteHomesGraph(appState: BetteHomesAppState) {
  
  composable(SPLASH_SCREEN) {
    SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SETTINGS_SCREEN) {
    SettingsScreen(
      restartApp = { route -> appState.clearAndNavigate(route) },
      openScreen = { route -> appState.navigate(route) }
    )
  }

  composable(LOGIN_SCREEN) {
    LoginScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SIGN_UP_SCREEN) {
    SignUpScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(MAP_SCREEN) {
    MapsScreen(snackbarHostState = SnackbarHostState(), navController = appState.navController, fetchLocationUpdates = appState.fetchLocationUpdates )
    }
  composable(GEOMARKER_SCREEN) {
    GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel = GeoMarkerViewModel())
  }
```

MainActivity.kt file for fetchLocationUpdates():

```
private fun fetchLocationUpdates(){
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        fusedLocationClient.locationFlow().collect {
          it?.let{ location ->
            geoMarkerViewModel.setCurrentLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit of a Compose newbie myself, and I haven't seen the pattern with `rememberAppState()` that you're using, but I think what's happening is this:

First, to be sure you understand the terminology, a *remembered* variable is one where the previous value, if there is one, from a previous call to the function is retrieved and used to initialize it. It is used for variables that should not be recomputed from scratch every time there is a recomposition. For example, scroll position of a scrollable list would be kept in a remembered variable. When something changes, like the user clicking a checkbox, that causes a recomposition. You don't want the list to immediately jump back to the top every time the user touches anything. In this case, Compose provides the `rememberScrollState()` function that can be used for remembering scroll state through recompositions.

There are a number of UI-related variables that should be kept ("remembered") every time there is a recomposition. Things like which screen is selected in the nav controller or what the current state of the snack bar is. It looks like you have wrapped a bunch of these into a single data class, BetteHomesAppState, to keep from having them cluttering your top level composable. These variables can then be accessed through the `appState` variable.

This is accomplished with the `rememberAppState()` function, which is defined to take all the parameters and pass them into an instance of BetteHomesAppState that is remembered.

---

Let's pretend `fetchLocationUpdates` doesn't exist for now.

In your current code, each of the parameters of the function has a default value defined using an `=` and an expression after the type of the parameter. Your function could have been declared with no arguments like this:

```
@Composable
fun rememberAppState() { // <- Zero-argument function
  val navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
  val snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
  val snackbarManager: SnackbarManager = SnackbarManager
  val resources: Resources = resources()
  val coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  remember(snackbarHostState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope) {
    BetteHomesAppState(navController, snackbarHostState, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope)
  }
}
```

but this would make it impossible to customize any of these values from where you are calling the `rememberAppState()` function. In your actual app, there's probably no reason to change them, but you might want to be able to unit test `rememberAppState()` by passing in alternative parameters.  [Read here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#default-arguments) to understand how parameters with default arguments work in Kotlin.

---

But in your current version of the function, you have an additional function parameter, `fetchLocationUpdates`, which has no default argument defined. After the parameter type, there is no `=` followed by an expression creating the default value. This means you *have* to pass a value for this argument when calling `rememberAppState()`. That's the issue the compiler is complaining about.

Theoretically, to make the code compile you could create a default value that is just an empty lambda, such as:

```
fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit = {}
```

However, this is useless to your actual app functionality. You don't want to be trying to remember a listener. It's not something that holds state. And you can't really declare it right at the beginning of your top level composable, because that would be defining it before the variables for States, Flows, or ViewModels it will eventually have to be working with.

You should remove `fetchLocationUpdates` completely from this function and your BetteHomesAppState class. Then you need to think about what you actually need to be doing in this listener. What do you want to happen when the location is updated on the Maps screen? If it is only updating things used by the Maps screen, then your MapsScreen composable should not be exposing a `fetchLocationUpdates`. It should be handling the location updates internally.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, appreciate it.If I remove the fetchLocationUpdates variable, how can I call the composable (MAP_SCREEN) which requires it as a parameter?

Comment: As I mentioned in the last paragraph, you might want to remove it as a parameter. But if you need to keep it, you would call the map screen like: `MapsScreen(snackbarHostState = appState.snackbarHostState, navController = appState.navController, fetchLocationUpdates = { /* your code that does something each time there is a new location emitted */ } )` It's not really any different from click listeners for buttons. Notice in your current code you're passing incorrect snackbar host state. You need to pass the remembered one from your `appState`.

Comment: Bear with me please. I'm merging two code bases, one which uses the above methods and another that uses simple AppNavigation, I'm lost which to keep, whether it's at all necessary to use AppState https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76977241/how-to-integrate-appnavigation-in-jetpack-compose

Comment: I’m still a newbie with Compose and haven’t used it in an app with navigation yet.