# How to integrate AppNavigation in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have two code bases that use slightly different structure for AppNavigation in android jetpack compose. I want to integrate these into one central app navigation. How do I do that in a standard way? In my `MainActivity.kt`, I have a call to AppNavigation which I want to use but also incorporate code from MakeItSoApp.kt. The `NavHost` contains code I want to include in my `MakeItSoApp`.

`MainActivity.kt`:

```
package com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.activities

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.navigation.AppNavigation
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.theme.ComposeGeoMarkerTheme
import com.android.composegeomarker.utils.locationFlow
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  private val fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient by lazy {
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
  }

  private val geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel by viewModels()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
      val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
      val navController = rememberNavController()
      ComposeGeoMarkerTheme {
        AppNavigation(
            navController = navController,
            snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
            geoMarkerViewModel = geoMarkerViewModel,
            this::fetchLocationUpdates
        )
      }
    }
  }

  private fun fetchLocationUpdates() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
      lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        fusedLocationClient.locationFlow().collect {
          it?.let { location ->
            geoMarkerViewModel.setCurrentLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude))
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`MakeItSoApp.kt`:

```
package com.example.makeitso

import android.Manifest
import android.content.res.Resources
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.ReadOnlyComposable
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.rememberCoroutineScope
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalConfiguration
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.navigation.NavGraphBuilder
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import androidx.navigation.compose.rememberNavController
import androidx.navigation.navArgument
import com.example.makeitso.common.composable.PermissionDialog
import com.example.makeitso.common.composable.RationaleDialog
import com.example.makeitso.common.snackbar.SnackbarManager
import com.example.makeitso.screens.edit_task.EditTaskScreen
import com.example.makeitso.screens.login.LoginScreen
import com.example.makeitso.screens.settings.SettingsScreen
import com.example.makeitso.screens.sign_up.SignUpScreen
import com.example.makeitso.screens.splash.SplashScreen
import com.example.makeitso.screens.tasks.TasksScreen
import com.example.makeitso.theme.MakeItSoTheme
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.ExperimentalPermissionsApi
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.isGranted
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.rememberPermissionState
import com.google.accompanist.permissions.shouldShowRationale
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope

@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun MakeItSoApp() {
  MakeItSoTheme {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
      RequestNotificationPermissionDialog()
    }

    Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
      val appState = rememberAppState()

      Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
          SnackbarHost(
            hostState = it,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
            snackbar = { snackbarData ->
              Snackbar(snackbarData, contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary)
            }
          )
        },
        scaffoldState = appState.scaffoldState
      ) { innerPaddingModifier ->
        NavHost(
          navController = appState.navController,
          startDestination = SPLASH_SCREEN,
          modifier = Modifier.padding(innerPaddingModifier)
        ) {
          makeItSoGraph(appState)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
@Composable
fun RequestNotificationPermissionDialog() {
  val permissionState = rememberPermissionState(permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)

  if (!permissionState.status.isGranted) {
    if (permissionState.status.shouldShowRationale) RationaleDialog()
    else PermissionDialog { permissionState.launchPermissionRequest() }
  }
}

@Composable
fun rememberAppState(
  scaffoldState: ScaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState(),
  navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
  snackbarManager: SnackbarManager = SnackbarManager,
  resources: Resources = resources(),
  coroutineScope: CoroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
) =
  remember(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope) {
    MakeItSoAppState(scaffoldState, navController, snackbarManager, resources, coroutineScope)
  }

@Composable
@ReadOnlyComposable
fun resources(): Resources {
  LocalConfiguration.current
  return LocalContext.current.resources
}

@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun NavGraphBuilder.makeItSoGraph(appState: MakeItSoAppState) {
  composable(SPLASH_SCREEN) {
    SplashScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SETTINGS_SCREEN) {
    SettingsScreen(
      restartApp = { route -> appState.clearAndNavigate(route) },
      openScreen = { route -> appState.navigate(route) }
    )
  }

  composable(LOGIN_SCREEN) {
    LoginScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(SIGN_UP_SCREEN) {
    SignUpScreen(openAndPopUp = { route, popUp -> appState.navigateAndPopUp(route, popUp) })
  }

  composable(TASKS_SCREEN) { TasksScreen(openScreen = { route -> appState.navigate(route) }) }

  composable(
    route = "$EDIT_TASK_SCREEN$TASK_ID_ARG",
    arguments = listOf(navArgument(TASK_ID) {
      nullable = true
      defaultValue = null
    })
  ) {
    EditTaskScreen(
      popUpScreen = { appState.popUp() }
    )
  }
}
```

AppNavigation in the other compose code `NavHost.kt`:

```
package com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.navigation

import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import androidx.navigation.compose.NavHost
import androidx.navigation.compose.composable
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.GeoMarkerViewModel
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.screens.GeoMarkerScreen
import com.android.composegeomarker.presentation.screens.MapsScreen

@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    navController: NavHostController,
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    geoMarkerViewModel: GeoMarkerViewModel,
    fetchLocationUpdates: () -> Unit
) {
  NavHost(
      navController = navController,
      startDestination = Screens.MapScreen.route
  ) {
    composable(Screens.MapScreen.route) {
      MapsScreen(
          snackbarHostState = snackbarHostState,
          navController = navController,
          fetchLocationUpdates
      )
    }
    composable(Screens.GeoMarkerScreen.route) {
      GeoMarkerScreen(geoMarkerViewModel)
    }
  }
}
```